# Amplify Next JS deployment error : Could not initialize categories for 'production': The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, deployment, web-deployment, aws-amplify

I'm working on a NextJS project - that uses AWS Amplify for authentication, environment management & deployment. My NextJS frontend is connected to Amplify's `production` environment in an auto-deploy setup using my `production` branch on GitHub. This frontend is connected to Amplify backend `production` that I am using for authentication.

Amplify CLI Version - 10.5.1
Next JS version - 12.1.5-canary.7

This setup has been working since 2 months but since today, I am unable to actually even get past the "Backend" step on AWS Amplify deployments. Here is the error log that I am facing. The key error, I feel lies in the line - `Could not initialize categories for 'production': The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`

```
2022-12-08T06:22:40.740Z [INFO]: [0mAmplify AppID found: d3k4n880hbvmjg. Amplify App name is: my-project-app-name[0m
    2022-12-08T06:22:40.787Z [INFO]: [0mBackend environment production found in Amplify Console app: my-project-app-name[0m
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.228Z [WARNING]: - Fetching updates to backend environment: production from the cloud.
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.510Z [WARNING]: - Building resource auth/coursemapfrontend
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.550Z [WARNING]: ✔ Successfully pulled backend environment production from the cloud.
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.905Z [WARNING]: ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.907Z [INFO]:  Could not initialize categories for 'production': The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.907Z [INFO]: Resolution: Review the error message and stack trace for additional information.
                                     Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.908Z [INFO]: 
    2022-12-08T06:22:41.909Z [INFO]: Session Identifier: f49926f2-49c5-4601-95c3-f5a9c63375d9
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.524Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.524Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.524Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.524Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.581Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
    2022-12-08T06:22:42.582Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
    Terminating logging...
```

Can someone please look at this and let me know what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please share the contents of `cli-inputs.json` & `amplify-meta.json` from the `/amplify/backend` folder please?